# Indicial equation power series, ODE and Frobenius theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider an ODE of the form $y'' + P(x)y' + Q(x)y = 0$ where $(x-x_0)P(x)$ and $(x-x_0)^2 Q(x)$ are analytic functions on $x_0$. The Frobenius Theorem asserts  that there exist at least one solution of the form:

$$y=(x - x_0)^r \cdot \sum_{k = 0}^\infty  a_k (x - x_0)^k  $$

where $r$ is an incognit, there is a formula for finding the $r$?

In some books appears, when $x_0 = 0$ that changes something? If this is the case, the formula is given by 
$$
r(r-1) + p_0 r + q_0  = 0
$$
where $q_0, p_0$ are the first terms of 
$$
\begin{align*}
P(x) &= (x-x_0)^{-1} \cdot \sum_{k = 0}^\infty p_k (x-x_0)^k    
\\ 
Q(x) &= (x-x_0)^{-2} \cdot \sum_{k = 0}^\infty q_k (x-x_0)^k   
\end{align*} 
$$
Thanks, I only want to know that.

Answer (score 2):

The indicial equation does not change when $x_0 \ne 0$. For a nice and simple derivation of the indicial equation see page **A52-A54** of the following reference

[*Nakhle H. Asmar, Partial Differential Equations with Fourier Series and Boundary Value Problem, Second Edition, Pages A52-A54*](https://books.google.com/books/about/Partial_Differential_Equations_with_Four.html?id=2FonAQAAIAAJ)

Also a more thorough explanation about the Frobenius method can be found in **sections 5.5 and 5.6** of this book

*[William E. Boyce, Richard C. Diprima, Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems, Tenth Edition, Section 5.4-5-5](https://books.google.com/books/about/Elementary_Differential_Equations_and_Bo.html?id=nYWcQgAACAAJ)*

To conclude, whether $x_0$ is $0$ or not, the indicial equation is

$$r(r-1) + p_0 r + q_0  = 0$$